# Connecting to Azure storage account thru proxy server

Tags: azure, proxy-server

My 'LocalClient' app is in a corporate LAN behind an HTTP proxy server (ISA). The first Azure API call i make - `CloudQueue.CreateIfNotExist()` - causes an exception: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. I tried following things:

- Added the `<System.Net> defaultProxy` element to app.config, but it doesn't seem to be working (Reference: http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2006/03/08/71663.aspx).
- I configured 'Microsoft Firewall Client for ISA Server', but that did not help either.
- Used a custom proxy handler as suggested here: http://dunnry.com/blog/2010/01/25/SupportingBasicAuthProxies.aspx. I am not able to get this working - getting a Configuration initialization exception.

As per MSDN, an HTTP proxy server can be specified in the connection string only in case of Development Storage (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758697.aspx):
`UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://myProxyUri`

Is there any way to connect to the Azure Storage thru a proxy server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **custom proxy solution** (the third thing i tried as mentioned in my original question) worked perfectly. The mistake i was doing earlier was not putting the `<configSections>` element at the beginning of `<configuration>` in app.config as required. On doing that, the custom proxy solution given [here](http://dunnry.com/blog/2010/01/25/SupportingBasicAuthProxies.aspx) solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

I actually found that the custom proxy solution was not required.

Adding the following to app.config (just before the `</configuration>`) did the trick for me:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
<proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Yes, that should work for most cases, I suppose. I had tried that too. But in my case, the proxy server (Squid) expected the username without domain. While the logged in username being sent to it (as per `useDefaultCredentials` setting) was in <domain>\<username> format. So it would not authenticate.

Comment: This worked for me too (my application was hanging when I attempted  to do any operations on a table).

Answer (score -1):

**To by pass the proxy then please use like below, it works as expected and same has been tested.**

```
public class AzureUpload {

    // Define the connection-string with your values
    /*public static final String storageConnectionString =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
        "AccountName=your_storage_account;" +
        "AccountKey=your_storage_account_key";*/
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=test2rdrhgf62;" +
            "AccountKey=1gy3lpE7Du1j5ljKiupjhgjghjcbfgTGhbntjnRfr9Yi6GUQqVMQqGxd7/YThisv/OVVLfIOv9kQ==";

    // Define the path to a local file.
    static final String filePath = "D:\\Project\\Supporting Files\\Jar's\\Azure\\azure-storage-1.2.0.jar";
    static final String file_Path = "D:\\Project\\Healthcare\\Azcopy_To_Azure\\data";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            //String storageConnectionString = RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings().get("StorageConnectionString");
            //Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("132.186.192.234",8080));
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "102.122.15.234");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "ad001\\empid001");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "pass!1");
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();


            // Get a reference to a container.
            // The container name must be lower case
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("rpmsdatafromhospital");

            // Create the container if it does not exist.
            container.createIfNotExists();

            // Create a permissions object.
            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

            // Include public access in the permissions object.
            containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

            // Set the permissions on the container.
            container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);

            // Create or overwrite the new file to blob with contents from a local file.
            /*CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("azure-storage-1.2.0.jar");
            File source = new File(filePath);
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());*/

            String envFilePath = System.getenv("AZURE_FILE_PATH");

            //upload list of files/directory to blob storage
            File folder = new File(envFilePath);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                File source = new File(envFilePath+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName()+ " upload successful");

              }
              //directory upload
              /*else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                File source = new File(file_Path+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
              }*/
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**.Net or C# then please add below code to "App.config"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>

    <system.net> 
     <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
       <proxy usesystemdefault="true" /> 
     </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>

</configuration>
```