# Unable to create container on Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create azure storage using follwing simple code.

Tried manually for cross check working fine manually.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

    //Create the blob client object.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    //Get a reference to a container to use for the sample code, and create it if it does not exist.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sascontainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

getting error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

App.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ashuthinks;AccountKey=MYKEY"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you're sitting behind a proxy server. You would need to configure proxy settings (most likely in app.config file).

Comment: which proxy setting :O can you help me in that?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994004/connecting-to-azure-storage-account-thru-proxy-server) for more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />` in to your configuration file explained below.

```
<configuration> 
 <system.net> 
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
    <proxy usesystemdefault="true" /> 
   </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
<configuration>
```